operator (and / &&) blade not working in laravel
I am working on Laravel 10.
It happens that I want to display a livewire component depending on the boolean value that the size and color column has. I tried the following code, but it always takes the first (if), I tried these forms and nothing.
enter image description here
I tried these ways and nothing.
enter image description here
Can you please tell me where I am going wrong.
I didn't find more information

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
